# Angular Material - Sort the data for mat-table

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, angular-material, angular-material-table

I am using Angular Material. How can I sort the data?

HTML file

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">


    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.assetId}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.assetName}} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Weight </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cpuName}} </td>
    </ng-container>


    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Symbol </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.hddName}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

.ts file

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';
import { AddAssetService } from '../shared/add-asset.service';
export interface Element {
  assetId: any;
  assetName: any;
  cpuName: any;
  hddName:  any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-material-two',
  templateUrl: './material-two.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./material-two.component.css']
})
export class MaterialTwoComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource:any;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort!: MatSort;
  constructor(private service:AddAssetService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

   this.assetGrid();
   this.ngAfterViewInit()
    console.log(this.dataSource);
  }
  assetGrid() {
    this.service.GetAssets().subscribe(user=>{
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(user);
       console.log("this.listData",this.dataSource);
       console.log("this.user",user)
    });
  }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

}
```

Getting the error:

> core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'sort' of undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid this error

> core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'sort' of undefined.

by checking **`this.dataSource` must not be `undefined` nor `null`** first before assigning as below:

> .component.ts

```js
if (this.dataSource) {
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

---

## Concerns

### Concern 1: Missing implements `AfterViewInit`

You must implement `AfterViewInit` on your component. Otherwise, `ngAfterViewInit` will not be executed. And remove calling `this.ngAfterViewInit` method from `ngOnInit` method.

> .component.ts

```js
import { AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

export class MaterialTwoComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.assetGrid();
    console.log(this.dataSource);
  }

  ...
}
```

### Concern 2: `matColumnDef` must be exact with property name

`matColumnDef` must be the same as the data's property name. If not, the sorting will not works. Hence, you also need to update `displayedColumns` for the properties.

> .component.html

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="assetId">
  ...
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="assetName">
  ...
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="cpuName">
  ...
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="hddName">
  ...
</ng-container>
```

> .component.ts

```js
displayedColumns: string[] = ['assetId', 'assetName', 'cpuName', 'hddName'];
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sqrqfl)

---

## References

[Angular Material Table Sorting](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sorting)